# Updating OpenSSL on a SLES11 server

Tags: openssl, sles

We are concerned with the OpenSSL vulnerabilities and are running a SLES11SP1 server. unfortunately, due to admin reasons, our support expired, and so we are looking at manually upgdating OpenSSL and its required libraries manually.  Is there a script, or recommended way to get the latest version of OpenSSL and make either an RPM or install the modules directly on the OS ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible without updating most of the system.  I tried the same with a CentOS 5.x and ended up wasting a lot of time.

What you could do (tried this, too, but ended up upgrading the whole system instead) is to install the sources of OpenSSL and your web server etc. -- whatever you wish to run with your new SSL, then compile these with a different compile root, e.g. in `/opt`.  It will, however, not be easy (to say the least) to compile OpenSSL against your old system libraries - I had that problem anyway.

A remaining problem will be that no easy upgrade route is available when a newer version of OpenSSL is released.

One workaround (wildly brainstorming now) could be to run a virtual machine with a newer system, running your SSL-based services, if there is no way of upgrading the (guest) OS.

Another workaroud would be to compile these services (like apache) against a static build of openSSL (which you would need to compile) - again lots of work.

Answer (score 1):

> In August of 2014, SUSE released the “SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 Security Module”, providing enhancements to SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 SP3, and later SP4.

```
zypper in curl-openssl1 wget-openssl1
```

Then make sure to use the right alternative, check:

```
update-alternatives --display curl
```

see: https://www.suse.com/documentation/suse-best-practices/singlehtml/securitymodule/securitymodule.html

Comment: related: [How to upgrade to SLES/SLED 11 SP4](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7016711)

Answer (score 0):

`zypper up` as root from a terminal should do the trick.

Comment: Does not work, as the support is expired and SUSE is no more providing updates for the version we are using. I am looking for an alternate way to install OpenSSL, one where I can just install the right RPM files and get everything updated for OpenSSL and its dependencies.

Comment: You can either compile from source or create your own RPMs. Here's the latest source : http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1h.tar.gz . Instructions here : http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation .